# PS not rendering

Tags: errors, rendering

Update 2: I've found the same error report here: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11957&f=19 However this individual is using LyX and I'm using TeXWorks. So "So it seems the error has something to do with Pk rendering and by selecting Dvips from the menu -> View -> Render method, Yap no longer complains about the postscript specials. I am not sure yet exactly why this error occurs (maybe because it needs ghostscript installed somewhere specific)." by mainiacfreakus Isn't advice that works for me...

Update 1: I uninstalled and re-installed my MikTeX distribution to no avail.

What to do now?

So I finally figured out how to get the `--shell-escape` option into the into the `-tex-option=` line under `Edit->Preferences->Typesetting` in TeXWorks and 
load the `auto-pst-pdf` package. This information saturates the internet and - at the same time - is nowhere to be found. (I figure this process is a sort of hazing ritual for those new to PSTricks.) But now no PS graphics appear in the PDF or DVI after compiling.

I'm attempting to put some simple graphs into a document.

Here is an example of code that doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amstext}[1995/01/25] \RequirePackage{amsbsy}[1995/01/20]
\RequirePackage{amsopn}[1995/01/20] \RequirePackage{amsgen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}



\begin{document}

This is a test document.

\begin{align}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
\rput[bl](0,0){\rnode{A}{TEST1}}
\rput[tr](3,3){\rnode{B}{TEST2}}
\ncline{->}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

When I open up the DVI I find the following error report:

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Some PostScript specials could not be rendered.
Data: Error: /undefined in tx@Dict
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   PermitFileReading   --nostringval--   PermitFileWriting   --nostringval--   -39321600   -39321600   39321600   39321600   5594037   0   5594037
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1914   1   3   %oparray_pop   1913   1   3   %oparray_pop   1897   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--   --dict:95/300(L)--   --dict:37/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript  9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Dvi\Ghostscript.cpp
Line: 372
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition, 64-bit Service Pack 1 (build 7601)
Invokers: explorer
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This test code actually produces two PDFs now. One with the text - one with the graphic. The PDF with the text has the title 'test' because I named it that. The one with the graphic has the title 'test-autopp'.

Comment: I have no problem with Ghostscript; however, `align` typesets twice its contents, so it's confusing `auto-pst-pdf`. Do you really need `align`? `equation` seems the best, for a single diagram.

Comment: I suppose I don't need `align`. However the rendering issue persists with or without.

Comment: I've just discovered XY-pic. This seems like the better option than working with PSTricks for the time being. All I need to do in my paper is build exactly the type of diagrams XY-pic is built for. (I'm studying a class of graphs as an algebra.) Moreover I simply don't have the rendering issues with XY-pic. XY-pic doesn't solve my Maple rendering problem however. And I would like to have the ability to use a more robust graphics package in the future.

Comment: @Mike include your **Update:1** and **Update :2** at the bottom of your question to make it clearly visible to all and does not break readability.

Comment: @Mike: I have no problem with your example. I used current TeXLive 2012

Answer (score 2):

The setting of TeXworks should be like:

[image]

Then I have no problem with your example. I used current TeXLive 2012 under Linux. With MikTeX it should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is an answer which came up on google.

You need `render >> method = dvips`. You can change the default in Options.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As it stands now, you wrote more a comment than an answer (I know, you do not have enough reputation for writing comment). Please write more elaborate: In what program this option must be changed on which place? Are there perhaps additional steps or caveats?

Comment: See Update 2 above. I've never used LyX and don't really want to. I would rather learn LaTeX.